# How do I strip the characters from this string?

Tags: ruby

```
"/home/chief/project/public/system/uploads/000/000/001/original/1/1.flv
```

to this:

```
  /system/uploads/000/000/001/original/1/1.flv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "/home/chief/project/public/system/uploads/000/000/001/original/1/1.flv"
chopped = str.sub(/.*\/public/, "") #=> "/system/uploads/000/000/001/original/1/1.flv"
```

This will remove everything to the left of public (including /public). This way your code isn't specific to one location, but rather it is more portable in that you can have anything in front of /public, and it will still strip the characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "/home/chief/project/public/system/uploads/000/000/001/original/1/1.flv"
s.sub("/home/chief/project/public", "")
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  How about if I want to strip off the end of it and make it like /home/chief/project/public/system/uploads/000/000/001/.  Would that require a regular expression?  Considering that the numbers after original would be different.

Comment: If you add this line afterwards:
s.sub("/original/1/1.flv", "")
it should work for you. There might be slightly better ways which I don't know as I haven't done Ruby for a while, but what I've shown should do the trick.

Comment: @dean...`Considering that the numbers after original would be different` is what she said..your solution wont work...

Answer (score 0):

You should specify in which language.
Using sed is trivial.

```
echo "\"/home/chief/project/public/system/uploads/000/000/001/original/1/1.flv" | sed -e 's-\"/home/chief/project/public--'
```